# In mysql workbench 'select top' is not working... how can i access top 5 in table?

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch top 5 data from my table.

I try with "TOP" query (Ref by, following link), but it's not working for me.

Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)!

Can some one suggest for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the link you have provided? it's written there plain and clear.

Comment: you must click on that link..test your code... if you have problem ask a Clear question to get GOOD answer

Comment: yes, while using that query(SELECT TOP) in mysql its not working

Comment: and it shouldn't . Read the MySQL part in your link.....

Comment: then how will i get the top rows?

Comment: Please share more details, like the query you are currently using and a clear error message. If there is no error thrown, please explain what you mean by "not working"

Answer (score 0):

From the link that you have provided:

> ```
> SELECT column_name(s)
> FROM table_name
> WHERE condition
> LIMIT number;
> ```

`SELECT TOP` is SqlServer syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT TOP <Number> <column_name(s)> 
    FROM <table_name> 
    WHERE <condition>;
```

For this SQL query corresponding MYSQL query is

```
    SELECT <column_name(s)> 
    FROM <table_name> 
    WHERE <condition>
    LIMIT number;
```

Using TOP will give the error.